# Understanding the multivariate normal density proportional

Tags: density-function, proportion, multivariate-normal-distribution

I don't understand the second line of the following equation
[image]

I get:
$$f(x) \propto exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu))$$
$$=exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu)$$

Would be nice if somebody tells me where my mistake is - seems like I don't understand some matrix-related calculation rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu^\top \Sigma^{-1} x$ is a scalar (which you can think of as a $1 \times 1$ matrix), so it is equal to its transpose: $$\mu^\top \Sigma^{-1} x = (\mu^\top \Sigma^{-1} x)^\top = x^\top (\Sigma^{-1})^\top \mu = x^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mu.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. So since $\Sigma$ is symmetric so is $\Sigma^{-1}$ and therefor $(\Sigma^{-1})^T = \Sigma^{-1}$?

Comment: @BlankerHans Yep